# Sending muliple occurrences of id to a request in jmeter

Tags: loops, while-loop, jmeter, infinite

From a soap XML response I need to get all the occurrences of an id (This part already done using Match No being set to -1 in Regex extractor).

And then I need to send these ids to a subsequent request. That is, the request needs to be fired as many times as of the total number of occurrences of the id, we can call it as `ID_matchNr`. (This is the total occurrences I got from the Regex extractor).

I used a while loop and a counter. The while loop works until the `ID_matchNr`, but it doesn't stop there, that while loop is infinite. How to fix this?

My counter's reference name is `count` and the field name in my request is `${__V(ID_${count})}`. And while loop's condition is `${count}<=${ID_matchNr}`. I also tried using a beanshell to save the `ID_matchNr` to another variable and then use it in while condition instead of directly using `ID_matchNr`. Still running infinitely.

Comment: You should also provide your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller)?

Given you have [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) in form of:

```
ID_1=foo
ID_2=bar
ID_3=baz
ID_matchNr=3
```

[image]

Add ForEach Controller to your Test Plan and configure it like:

[image]

And put the "subsequent" sampler as a child of the ForEach Controller and refer the generated subsequent ID value as `${CURRENT_ID}` where required

[image]

More information on the concept with the real-life example: [Using Regular Expressions in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-regular-expressions-jmeter)

Comment: The images are not visible to me,Dmitri. Can you please write the order of the samplers? I tried For Each controller with inputVar as the input variable prefix in the controller and returnVar as the id to be used in subsequent request. In request, I called it as ${returnVar}. But it is not even starting the for each loop.It's only executing the sampler which generates the id and stops.

Comment: I got it fixed by checking the _ in for each controller.

Comment: The images are hosted at https://imgur.com/, if you able to see anything from there - you will see the images in the post. Just in case try re-opening this page in "porno mode"